# Macro-like function with macros inside the body

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to make macro-like function that will "create" few lines of new macros.
ARM-GCC preprocessor is not happy with that macro-like function. Any ideas how to achieve same functionality without extern tools?

```c
#define SML_DEBUG(_name) \
    #if defined(DEBUG_##_name) \
        #define _name##_LOG DEBUG_HANDLER \
    #else \
        #define _name##_LOG(...) \
    #endif
```

Task is to create macros for functions for printing debug stuff.

Eg.,

```c
#define DEBUG
#define DEBUG_HANDLER log
#define DEBUG_TEST // Enable debug prints for test module
#define SML_DEBUG(TEST) // Should create test_LOG macro or its placeholder if DEBUG build is disabled

void foo(void)
{
    TEST_LOG("Hello World\n"); // Will redirect to "log" function(defined by DEBUG_HANDLER)
}
```

Error is:

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
  182 | #define SML_DEBUG(_name) \
      |                        ^
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen such error message "preprocessor is not happy". Can you post the real GCC error?

Comment: After a macro is processed, the resulting source code is not processed as a preprocessor directive (such as `#if`, `#else`, and `#endif`) even if it resembles one.

Comment: @273K Added, sorry.

Comment: The specific error you are getting is because `#` in a function-like macro (not a macro-like function) is supposed to be used as the stringizing operator, as in `#define MakeString(x) #x`, per C 2018 6.10.3.2 1. Since you have `#if`, and `if` is not a parameter name, the compiler complains. (That is a constraint paragraph, so the compiler is required to complain about it.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Any idea how to dodge that? Only way is to manually copy-paste body for every module I need.

Comment: `how to dodge that?` is a very open question, C has 50 years, there are endless logging utilities, modules, written by hundreds of people. For example https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/services/logging/index.html#logging-in-a-module . For example, idea, instead of `#define DEBUG_TEST`, you could just `#define TEST_LOG DEBUG_HANDLER` or `#define TEST_LOG DEBUG_NOTHING`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error you are getting is because `#` in a function-like macro (not a macro-like function) is supposed to be used as the stringizing operator, as in `#define MakeString(x) #x`, per C 2018 6.10.3.2 1. Since you have `#if`, and `if` is not a parameter name, the compiler complains. (That is a constraint paragraph, so the compiler is required to complain about it.)

Even if `#` were allowed in a macro replacement list, the source code resulting from processing a macro is not processed as a preprocessor directive (such as `#if`, `#else`, and `#endif`) even if it resembles one, per C 2018 6.10.3.4 3.

Instead of attempting to define a macro with conditional source code, you can conditionally define a macro:

```
#if defined DEBUG_TEST
    #define _TEST_LOG DEBUG_HANDLER
#else
    #define _TEST_LOG(...)
#endif
```

That means you would need to repeat those lines for each module you want to enable/disable logging for, but that is what source code editors and scripting languages are for. Not everything should be done in the C preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. My function-like macro should expand `SML_DEBUG(TEST)` to the example you wrote.  Just to make easier to add debug logging to the module/driver since I have plan to add option for multiple levels(error, warning, info, verbose) so copy-paste seems pesky to do.
Seems like I have to stick to c/p and rename :|

Comment: Added. [Here is result](https://github.com/silvio3105/SML/blob/dev/SML.hpp#L187)